# How to move file from folder A to folder B in python?

Tags: python, file, line, move, catalog

What am I doing wrong
and what do i need to improve?

```
import os
source = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ala.txt"
destination = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\zzz.txt"

try:
    if os.path.exists(destination):
        print("There is already a file there")
    else:
        os.replace(source,destination)
        print(source+" was moved")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(source+" was not found")
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? Your code works as expected, yes?

Answer (score 4):

You can try importing shutil and calling
shutil.move(source,destination).
The shutil module provides functions for moving files, as well as entire folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the shutil package like this :

```
import os
import shutil

source = r"C:\Users\omkar\Desktop\source"
destination = r"C:\Users\omkar\Desktop\destination"

allfiles = os.listdir(source)

for f in allfiles:

    shutil.move(source+ r"\\" + f, destination)
```